# update data in SQLite does not update

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-studio, listview

I'm watching tutorials on SQL and I got stuck in updating existing information. so far I'm able to add and delete, I tried using the add method in SQL with little changes to function as update method but it does not work, it does not show an error or crash but the exiting data is not changing. also, there is a toString() override method inside the model class, is there a way to not use it and get string results? because without toString() it shows some random stuff.

here is the java activity

```
public class DbTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etName;
    Button addName;
    Button updateName;
    ListView lv;

    dbTester db;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    PersonModel model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_db_test);

        etName = findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        addName =findViewById(R.id.add_name);
        updateName = findViewById(R.id.update_name);
        lv = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        db = new dbTester(DbTestActivity.this);

        show_data_on_lv();

        addName.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            try {

            }catch (Exception e)
            {

                Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR ADDING!!!\n"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            String name = String.valueOf(etName.getText());
            model =new PersonModel(-1, name);
            db.insert_data(model);
            show_data_on_lv();
        });
        updateName.setOnClickListener(view -> {


        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                try {
                    model = new PersonModel();
                    model.setName("updated name");
                    db.update_data(model);
                    show_data_on_lv();
                    Toast.makeText(DbTestActivity.this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(DbTestActivity.this, "ERROR UPDATING!!!\n"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void show_data_on_lv() {
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(DbTestActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, db.get_data());
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

here is the xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DbTestActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="add"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:text="update"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_name" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is the SQL helper

```
public class dbTester extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE = "PERSON_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "PERSON_NAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";

    public dbTester(Context context) {
        super(context, "person.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE+" ("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+COLUMN_NAME+" TXT )";
        db.execSQL(createTableStatement);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE);
    }

    public List<PersonModel>get_data()
    {
        List <PersonModel> return_data = new ArrayList<>();

        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                int personID = cursor.getInt(0);
                String personName = cursor.getString(1);

                PersonModel personModel = new PersonModel(personID, personName);
                return_data.add(personModel);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else
        {

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return return_data;
    }
    public boolean insert_data(PersonModel model)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, model.getName());

        long insert = db.insert(TABLE, null, cv);

        if (insert == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public boolean delete_data(PersonModel model)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String queryString = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE+ " WHERE "+COLUMN_NAME+" = "+model.getName();
        db.execSQL(queryString);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            return true;
        }
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean update_data(PersonModel model)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, model.getName());

        db.update(TABLE, cv, COLUMN_NAME + " =? ", new String[]{COLUMN_NAME});

    return true;
    }
}
```

here is the model class used

```
public class PersonModel {
private String name;
private int id;

public PersonModel(){}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PersonModel{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", id=" + id +
            '}';
}

public PersonModel(int id, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
}
```

Comment: That's quite a bit of code to check out. I think this might get more attn on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) QA site.

Answer (score 0):

For the update to actually update something, the update query should match at least one row. Here

> ```
> db.update(TABLE, cv, COLUMN_NAME + " =? ", new String[]{COLUMN_NAME});
> ```

you're matching the name column with the name of the column. Use a value for the name in the string array of values to bind, e.g. `model.getName()` instead of `COLUMN_NAME` (with the old value of name, not the one you want to update the table with).

> also, there is a toString() override method inside the model class, is there a way to not use it and get string results? because without toString() it shows some random stuff.

You can override `getView()` in your adapter to produce the output you want. The default implementation in `ArrayAdapter` uses `toString()`.

Comment: thank you so much for your thorough explaination @laalto I have a better understanding of ` update() ` in sqlite now. the updated data is still not showing up in the ` listView ` I think it might be the ` arrayAdapter ` should have ` notify() ` or something similar I'm not sure but im doing trying to place it but still not showing up. I need the name to be changed from any entered name to ( updated name ) when th list item is clicked